# Azure Pipeline Xamarin iOS build with .NET 6

Tags: azure-devops, xamarin.ios, azure-pipelines

I am trying to setup a YAML Pipeline for .NET 6 based Xamarin iOS app but running into different issues with different approaches:

When using below task, I am getting error "The TargetFramework value 'net6.0-ios' was not recognized" - I am guessing that this task uses an older MSBuild version:

```
task: XamariniOS@2
  displayName: Build iOS App 
  inputs:
    solutionFile: Sam.Com.iOS/Sam.Com.iOS.csproj
    configuration: Release
    buildForSimulator: false
    packageApp: true
```

And when I use below task, I am getting error "No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain" - I can see that provisioning profile task executes successfully:

```
task: Bash@3
  displayName: Build iOS App
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      cd Sam.Com.iOS
      dotnet publish -f net6.0-ios -c Release
```

Here is the complete YAML:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-12'
  demands:
  - MSBuild

steps:
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Install an Apple certificate'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'certificate.p12'
    certPwd: '$(P12password)'
    keychain: 'temp'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install an Apple provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'profile.mobileprovision'

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: .NET Version
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: 6.0.x

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Install Workloads
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dotnet nuget locals all --clear
      dotnet workload restore --source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet7/nuget/v3/index.json --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 6.7.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 6.7.x

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Restore Nuget'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dotnet restore Sam.Com.sln

#- task: Bash@3
#  displayName: Build iOS App
#  inputs:
#    targetType: 'inline'
#    script: |
#      cd Sam.Com.iOS
#      dotnet publish -f net6.0-ios -c Release

- task: XamariniOS@2
  displayName: Build iOS App 
  inputs:
    solutionFile: Sam.Com.iOS/Sam.Com.iOS.csproj
    configuration: Release
    buildForSimulator: false
    packageApp: true
```

I had been using AppCenter for the builds till now, but that isn't supported since I upgraded to .NET 6 SDK styled project. So, I am setting up Azure Pipelines for automated builds. Please suggest. TIA.

EDIT: Created a sample project here: https://github.com/SnapADrag0n/XamariniOSPipeline

Comment: To build a Xamarin.iOS app, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xamarin?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). Please try to use `<TargetFramework>net6.0-ios15.0</TargetFramework>` and check if it works. If it's convenient, would you please share a sample project that can reproduce the issue? SO that I can test from my side.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT I followed the same guide for YAML setup.
When I update target framework, I get "The TargetFramework value 'net6.0-ios15.0' was not recognized" error. Does "XamariniOS@2" even support .NET 6?
I will share a sample project soon.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT Added a link to sample project